# Modify MDT wizard to automate computer naming

Tags: html, xml, vbscript, mdt

Situation:

> I am imaging new systems using MDT Lite-Touch. I am trying to
> customize the wizard to automate the naming of new systems so that
> they include a prefix "AG-", a department code which is selected from
> a drop-down box in the wizard page (eg. "COMM"), and finally the
> serial number of the computer being imaged, so that my result in this
> case would be "AG-COMM-1234567"

Progress:

> 1. I first created the HTML page which I will include below and added a script to the page to concatenate the pieces into a variable called
>    OSDComputername which, for testing, I could output in a msgbox and get
>    to display correctly.
>
>    - The problem with this is I don't know how to trigger the script then assign it to the OSDComputername variable that is used throughout
>      the rest of the Light-Touch process.
> 2. I changed the script to a function and added it to DeployWiz_Initization.vbs then used the Initialization field in WDS to
>    call it. I'll include the function below.
>
>    - The problem with this is I would get "Undefined Variable" for OSDComputername and I am not sure it is pulling the data from the HTML
>      correctly.
> 3. I tried adding the scripting into the customsettings.ini file after the "OSDComputername="
>
>    - This resulted in the wizard just outputting my code in text as the computer name.
> 4. I am now trying adding variables to "Properties=" (eg.DepartmentName) in the customsettings.ini, pulling thier value
>    from the HTML Form and setting that value to the variable in my
>    function in DeployWiz_Initization.vbs and calling them after
>    "OSDComputername=" in the fashion "OSDComputername="AG-" &
>    %DepartmentName%" in customsettings.ini
>
>    - I am rebuilding right now and will see how this goes

Any help would be appreciated.

The HTML page:

```
<HTML>
<H1>Configure the computer name.</H1>
<span style="width: 95%;">
    <p>Please answer the following questions.  Your answers will be used to formulate the computer's name and description.</p>
        <FORM NAME="TestForm">
            <p>Departmental Prefix: <!-- <label class=ErrMsg id=DepartmentalPrefix_Err>* Required (MISSING)</label> -->
                <SELECT NAME="DepartmentalPrefix_Edit" class=WideEdit>
                    <option value="AADC">AADC</option>
                    <option value="AEM">AEM</option>
                    <option value="AIP">AIP</option>
                    <option value="COM">COM</option>
                    <option value="DO">DO</option>
                    <option value="DSOC">DSOC</option>
                    <option value="EDU">EDU</option>
                    <option value="EPE">EPE</option>
                    <option value="ITN">ITN</option>
                    <option value="LA">LA</option>
                    <option value="OAP">OAP</option>
                    <option value="SML">SML</option>
                    
                </SELECT>
            </p>

            <p><span class="Larger">Client's Net<u class=larger>I</u>D:</span>
            <INPUT NAME="ClientNetID" TYPE="TEXT" ID="ClientNetID" SIZE="15"></p>

            <p>Building: <!-- <label class=ErrMsg id=Building_Err>* Required (MISSING)</label> -->
                <SELECT NAME="Building_Edit" class=WideEdit>
                    <option value="Academic Surge Facility A">Academic Surge Facility A</option>
                    <option value="Academic Surge Facility B">Academic Surge Facility B</option>
                    <option value="Caldwell">Caldwell</option>
                    <option value="Kennedy">Kennedy</option>
                    <option value="Roberts">Roberts</option>
                    <option value="Warren">Warren</option>
                </SELECT>
            </p>

            <p>
                <span class="Larger">Room <u class=larger>N</u>umber:</span>
                <input type=text id="RoomNumber" name=RoomNumber size=15 />
            </p>
        </FORM>           
</span>
</HTML>
```

The Function:

```
Function SetComputerName

OSDComputerName = "AG-" & oEnvironment.Item("DepartmentalPrefix_Edit")
ComputerDescription = oEnvironment.Item("DepartmentalPrefix_Edit") & ", " & oEnvironment.Item("ClientNetID") & ", " & oEnvironment.Item("RoomNumber") & " " & oEnvironment.Item("Building_Edit")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved!

The HTML page:

```
<H1>Configure the computer name.</H1>
<p>Please answer the following questions.  Your answers will be used to formulate the computer's name and description.</p>

<FORM NAME="SetComputerNameForm">
    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">D</u>epartmental Prefix:</LABEL><br />
        <SELECT NAME="DepartmentalPrefix_Edit" ID="DepartmentalPrefix_Edit" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=D>
            <option value="FOO">FOO</option>
            <option value="DOE">DOE</option>
            <option value="AFK">AFK</option>
            <option value="BBL">BBL</option>
            <option value="RTFM">RTFM</option>                  
        </SELECT>
    </p>


    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">C</u>lient's ID:</LABEL>
        <br />
        <INPUT NAME="ClientID" ID="ClientID" TYPE="text" ID="ClientID" SIZE="15" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=C />
        <label class=ErrMsg for=ClientID>* Required (MISSING)</label>


    </p>


    <p>
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">B</u>uilding:</LABEL><br />
        <SELECT NAME="Building_Edit" ID="Building_Edit" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName  AccessKey=B>
                <option value="ASA">ASA</option>
                <option value="ASB">ASB</option>
                <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
        </SELECT>
    </p>


    <p>         
        <LABEL class="Larger"><u class="Larger">R</u>oom Number:</span></LABEL>
        <br />
        <INPUT NAME="RoomNumber" ID="RoomNumber" TYPE="text" ID="RoomNumber" size="15" language=vbscript onpropertychange=ValidateSetComputerName AccessKey=R>
        <label class=ErrMsg for=RoomNumber>* Required (MISSING)</label>
    </p>

</FORM>
```

The Function:

```
Function ValidateSetComputerName
    ParseAllWarningLabels

    If Len(Document.SetComputerNameForm.ClientNetID.Value) < 1 OR Len(Document.SetComputerNameForm.RoomNumber.Value) < 1 THEN
        ButtonNext.disabled = true
    Else
        Dim Department
        Dim SerialNumber
        Dim CID
        Dim RoomNumber
        Dim BuildingName
        Dim Make
        Dim Model
        Department = Document.SetComputerNameForm.DepartmentalPrefix_Edit.Value
        SerialNumber = oEnvironment.Item("SerialNumber")
        CID = Document.SetComputerNameForm.ClientID.Value
        RoomNumber = Document.SetComputerNameForm.RoomNumber.Value
        BuildingName = Document.SetComputerNameForm.Building_Edit.Value
        Make = oEnvironment.Item("Make")
        Model = oEnvironment.Item("Model")

        oEnvironment.Item("OSDComputerName") = "AG-" & Department & "-" & Right(SerialNumber,7)
        oEnvironment.Item("ComputerDescription") = Department & ", " & CID & ", " & RoomNumber & " " & BuildingName & ", " & Make & " " & Model
        ButtonNext.disabled = false
    End If

End Function
```

The real change is in the Function how I needed to retrieve the values from my custom HTML screens. You will see in the working Function that I had to set each value using the format: Document.FormName.FieldName.Value

I could then use the built-in Environmental Items to collect the Make, Model, and Serial Number. Once I had all of the pieces, all of the user selections and built-in values, it was simply a matter of concatenating the strings in the order I wanted and assigning the value to the Environmental Items "OSDComputerName" and "ComputerDescription".

I also made use of ButtonNext.disabled to make all of the fields required before the user was able to continue to the next screen.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the mistake or how to approach the problem.